# Using a tuple in a file string for file names

Tags: python, string, file, tuples

I'm currently writing a forloop that will run a function iteratively chaning a certain parameter each time based on a tuple, then save the output. I'd like the file name for the output to match the variable that was run for that iteration. Here is my code and error:

```
#define tuple
range_length = (50, 75)

for i in range_length:
    evs.set_module('A2_ra_Ind_krig_3d', 'Krig Settings',  'Range': i})
    evs.set_module('A2_ra_Ind_krig_3d', 'Properties', 'Execute', True)
#Where error is
    file_string = '\\\\C:\\A2_Radium_Range_{0:.0f}'.format(range_length)
    evs.set_module('write evs field', 'Properties', 'Filename', file_string)
```

Error when ran:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__
```

Note, I simplified some of the code to focus on the error, which is related to the file string. Everything works up until that point. Any help with this would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to pass is actually the variable `i` instead of `range_length`. Therefore, the line should be

```
file_string = '\\\\C:\\A2_Radium_Range_{0:.0f}'.format(i)
```

Comment: wow! I've had some blonde moments but this takes the cake. Thank you!

Comment: @Melanie -- Instead of a "wow", please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem, that's how this site works.